# Can I use VST plug-ins in Logic?

Tags: logic-pro, vst, plugins

Logic only accepts Audio Unit plug-ins. Is there a way around this to use VST plug-ins too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [FXpansion VST to AU Adapter](http://www.fxpansion.com/index.php?page=5&tab=22) is a commercial tool
- [JVSTwRapper](http://jvstwrapper.sourceforge.net/) is free

Both seem to work equally well

Answer (score 0):

In general, the type of tool I'm looking for is called a "VST wrapper". When @Dr. Mayhem's answer goes out of date, you can search for VST wrappers and see what tools are available.